# Systems of differential equations involving analytic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve questions $(a)$ and $(b)$ related to the system of differential equations. I'm  struggling to understand. Can anyone give me some help with this questions?

Let $a, b_{i j}$ be analytic functions defined in a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\varphi ,\psi$ analytic in a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. In a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, consider

\begin{align}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
u_t + au_x + b_{11}u + b_{12}v  =  f, \\
v_x + b_{12}u + b_{22}v =  g,
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}

with the condition

\begin{align}
u(x,0)= \varphi(x) \,\,\ \mathrm{e} \,\,\ v(0,t) = \psi(x)
\end{align}

$(a)$ Let $(u, v)$ be a smooth solution in a neighborhood of origin. Prove that all derivatives of $u$ and $v$ at $0$ are expressed in terms of those of $a$,  $b_{ij}$,  $f$,  $g$,  $\varphi$ e $\psi$ in $0$.

$(b)$ Prove that there is an analytical solution $(u,v)$ in a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$.